# How to get permission r_ads_leadgen_automation in linkedin marketing api

Tags: linkedin-api

**adFormResponses** endpoint is giving below error although I have approved access for linkedin marketing platform.

> Not enough permissions to access: GET-account /adFormResponses

How to get permission `r_ads_leadgen_automation`?

Comment: any update on it?